# Webpack - background images not loading

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, css-loader

I'm fairly new to webpack but having some problems with css-loader or file-loader.

I'm trying to load a background-image but it doesn't work quite right. The background-image isn't shown, even though the devtools show the `background-image` style.

If I copy the `background-image` style to the `element.style` block, everything works fine. Am I making a stupid mistake somewhere?

The body tag should have a background image. The style appears in the developer tools and there are no errors:

[image: 1]

I can load the file `5a09e4424f2ccffb6a33915700f5cb12.jpg`, but the body has no background.

If I manually copy and paste css line to `element.style` in the DevTools, everything works:

[image: 2]

This happens if I bundle using `webpack-dev-server` or just `webpack` and in both Chrome and Firefox.

Other styles, such as `body { background-color: red }` work fine.

This is the webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    "entry": [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    "output": {
        "path": path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        "filename": "bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    "module": {
        "loaders": [
            {
                "test": /\.scss$/,
                "loaders": ["style", "css?sourceMap", "sass?sourceMap"]
            },
            { 
                test: /\.jpg$/, 
                loader: "file-loader" 
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './build'
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end? I am having the exact same problem

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is currently a bug when using sourceMap with css-loader. Removing sourceMap from your css loader should fix it.

```
"module": {
    "loaders": [
        {
            "test": /\.scss$/,
            "loaders": ["style", "css", "sass?sourceMap"]
        },
        { 
            test: /\.jpg$/, 
            loader: "file-loader" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Issue is related to: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/296

Comment: I was having the same issue and couldn't figure it out - this worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: @Antwan You should probably respond to this issue for the webpack team to fix sourcemaps: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/296

Answer (score 5):

It seems like browsers aren't fond of relative paths to background images on the body tag.  (see also [CSS Background image not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374534/css-background-image-not-loading) and [css background-image not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892374/css-background-image-not-working-properly))

Changing the code slightly seemed to do the trick:

- change the URL to an absolute URL: `background-image: url(http://localhost:8080/5a09e4424f2ccffb6a33915700f5cb12.jpg)`.  This is hardly ideal.
- add a class to body, and change the styles to reference this class:

```
<body class="foo">

.foo {
    background-image: url('../img/test.jpg');
}
```

Neither of these solve the real question, but do get you unstuck.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Absolute URL does indeed fix the problem, however adding a class to body doesn't work (at least in my environment). Also, the problem isn't specific to `<body>`, it also happens when trying to apply `background-image` to a `<div>` or any other element. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

After several hours around this, I just simply downgraded `css-loader`

```
npm install css-loader@4.3.0
```

Comment: This is a good quick fix. It appears there is something different between 4.3 and 5.0 that has so far eluded me.

Comment: @FoxMulder900 yes, it is a breaking change, according to semver

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with this problem for a day, I finally figured out how to rewrite urls within css using postcss

**webpack.config.js**

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const argv = {
    verbose:    _.includes(process.argv, '-v') || _.includes(process.argv, '--verbose'),
    json:       _.includes(process.argv, '--json'),
    production: _.includes(process.argv, '--production'),
};
module.exports = {
    cache:   true,
    devtool: argv.production ? "source-maps" : "eval",
    output: {
        path: 'public/build',
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: "/build/",
        pathinfo: true // use with devtool: "eval",
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: argv.production
                    ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader?sourceMap=1', [
                        'css-loader?sourceMap=1&importLoaders=1',
                        'postcss-loader?sourceMap=1',
                        'less-loader?sourceMap=1'
                    ]) : [
                        'style-loader?sourceMap=1',
                        'css-loader?sourceMap=1&importLoaders=1',
                        'postcss-loader?sourceMap=1',
                        'less-loader?sourceMap=1'
                    ].join('!')
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: argv.production
                    ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader?sourceMap=1', [
                        'css-loader?sourceMap=1&importLoaders=1',
                        'postcss-loader?sourceMap=1',
                    ]) : [
                        'style-loader?sourceMap=1',
                        'css-loader?sourceMap=1&importLoaders=1',
                        'postcss-loader?sourceMap=1',
                    ].join('!')
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
const argv = {
    verbose:    _.includes(process.argv, '-v') || _.includes(process.argv, '--verbose'),
    json:       _.includes(process.argv, '--json'),
    production: _.includes(process.argv, '--production'),
};
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')({
            browsers: [
                "> 5%",            // https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0
                "last 2 versions", // http://caniuse.com/
            ]
        }),
        require('postcss-url-mapper')(function(url) {
            return argv.production ? url : url.replace(new RegExp('^/'), 'http://localhost:3000/');
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Webpack generates the css and `<link>`s them via `blob:` urls, which seems to cause issues with loading background images.

**Development workaround**
Inline the images via the file-loader in development (creates large base64 string in the css)
But allows for hot-reloading.

**Production workaround**
Use the [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to serve the css as normal file.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your publicPath entry in output? eg:

publicPath: 'http://localhost:5000/', // absolute path req here for images in css to work with sourcemaps on. Must be actual numeric ip to access on lan.

https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the `~` in front of your files so that the webpack falls back to the loaders `require` to resolve the url.

```
background-url: (~assets/image/myimagefile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using, for example:

```
html {
   background: url(~/Public/img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

css-loader in webpack:

```
{
    test: /\.(css|eot|svg|ttf|woff|jpg|png)$/i,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: [{
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                minimize: true
            },
        }],
    }),
},
```

Result in bundle.css is:

```
html{background:url(/Public/img/bg-picking.jpg) no-repeat 50% fixed;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover}
```

Answer (score -1):

When having problems using img inside react you have to check your directory structure, is common to make a mistake calling a route that points to a parent directory.

eg: if you have this structure

-public
--images
---testImage.jpg
-components
--home
---index.js

if you try to use the below code inside index.js it will fail:

```
{background : url('/public/images/testImage.jpg')}
```

but if you are aware of the folder structure and use the [../] as shown in the code below to navigate to a outer folder I think it will work as it worked for me.

```
{background : url('../public/images/testImage.jpg')}
```

this problem happens many times when using relative routes, try [../] in your route until you position yourself on the proper level in your project directory structure and then just go to the directory you want using the proper route.