# webpack scss background image path error

Tags: sass, webpack

I have the following rule on line 258 of my style.scss file:

```
background: url(img/bg-light-grey.gif)
```

I then run the command `webpack` and it successfully builds.  I go to my webpage but I see I don't see the image included on my webpage. I open up chrome debugger and it says that line 258 of my style.scss has:

```
background: url(build/4932049asdfjaoi3j234.gif)
```

In my Chrome debugger, I replace that line with absolute url

```
background: url(http://localhost:8080/experiment/build/4932049asdfjaoi3j234.gif)
```

And now the image appears.

How do I get webpack to compile the file paths properly for my images?  Alternatively, I don't mind stringify or base64encode these things into my bundle.js file.  Whatever it takes to get these images to render properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[Webpack - background images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288886/webpack-background-images-not-loading)

I had to make a change in my webpack.config.js from

```
  { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: [ 'style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap' ]},
```

to

```
  { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'sass' ]},
```