# Can't display background image in node js

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm building a simple web page for a test I have to do using a node.js server. I can easily include an image via src like this:

`<img src="assets/young-woman.jpg">`

However, when I try to do this:

`style="background-image: url(assets/young-woman.jpg);"`

...it doesn't work.

I have tried following the various solutions to this problem such as: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/256 and this [Webpack - background images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288886/webpack-background-images-not-loading) but none of the solutions work for me.

It also works fine if I do it via the CSS like so:

```
.element {
    background-image: url(../assets/young-woman.jpg);
}
```

Clearly there must be something wrong with my webpack.config file?

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [{
                        loader: "css-loader", options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader", options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    }],
                    publicPath: '../',
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|gif)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]',
                        outputPath: 'img/'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        attrs: [':src']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].[contenthash].css",
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
            Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: ''
    }
}
```

When I try to load the resources in a browser I just get `Cannot GET /assets/young-woman.jpg`

I've tried installing express, but that also doesn't work for me and I get an error about *fs*. I can't seem to get my head around this. Is it a problem with my set up perhaps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried loading `http://localhost:3000/dist/assets/young-woman.jpg` in the browser?

Comment: Yes, tried that too

Answer (score -1):

javascript(part)

```
    const express = require("express");
    
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static("public")) ;
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });
    app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
    });
```

Inside project make a folder "public" containing folder css/style.css + image, just paste into css folder.
index.html header link to css folder:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

(+ link to javascript from body)
and css code:

```
   body{
   background: url("image.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover; etc. }
```

And it works!